# Appending data to list from a web-scraped JSON using urllib

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, urllib

Data scraped from website:

```
 {'data': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Bitcoin', 'symbol': 'BTC', 'website_slug': 'bitcoin', 'rank': 1, 'circulating_supply': 17290912.0, 'total_supply': 17290912.0, 'max_supply': 21000000.0, 'quotes': {'USD': {'price': 6468.27571485, 'volume_24h': 4319636048.09599, 'market_cap': 111842386177.0, 'percent_change_1h': -0.31, 'percent_change_24h': 0.01, 'percent_change_7d': 0.76}}, 'last_updated': 1538037891}, 'metadata': {'timestamp': 1538037295, 'error': None}}
```

I cannot access the `price` variable because it's nested in the list. Is there a way to do this in python?

I have tried:

```
databs.append(data.get('USD', {}).get('price'))
```

but this returns `None`

Complete code:

```
c_list = ["1","52", "1958","1042"]

databs = []

def get_values():
    t1 = time.time()
    for i in c_list:
        with urllib.request.urlopen("https://....") as url:
            data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
            #print(data) # This prints the list and i see the values are present
            databs.append(data.get('USD', {}).get('price'))
    a_current =databs[0]
    b_current =databs[1]
    c_current =databs[2]
    d_current =databs[3]
    print(databs)

while True:
    get_values()
```

returns `[None, None, None, None]`

Comment: `data['data']['USD']['price']`. I made the same mistake as you - you have a variable called data and a primary key `'data'`

Comment: This spits out 'KeyError: 'USD'

Comment: Did you try my edited version?

Comment: Use data["data"]["USD"].get("price")

Comment: can you provide url for replicating the scenario?

Comment: Apologies, full data is : 
{'data': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Bitcoin', 'symbol': 'BTC', 'website_slug': 'bitcoin', 'rank': 1, 'circulating_supply': 17290912.0, 'total_supply': 17290912.0, 'max_supply': 21000000.0, 'quotes': {'USD': {'price': 6468.27571485, 'volume_24h': 4319636048.09599, 'market_cap': 111842386177.0, 'percent_change_1h': -0.31, 'percent_change_24h': 0.01, 'percent_change_7d': 0.76}}, 'last_updated': 1538037891}, 'metadata': {'timestamp': 1538037295, 'error': None}}

Comment: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/

Comment: Err, that's completely different to the structure in your question. Please edit that into the question and remove the incorrect JSON structure. `data['data']['quotes']['USD']['price']`

Comment: Thanks, this worked

Answer (score 1):

To access nested dicts you can try something similar to this:

```
def getDictValue(dic, key):
    for item in key.split('.'):
        if item in dic:
            dic = dic[item]
        else:
            return None
    return dic
```

To access `price` for instance: `price = getDictValue(data, 'data.quotes.USD.price')`

Comment: Thanks, I will bare this in mind when doing further web scraping. For now, my loop works fine. :)